# Calling C# dll in vbscript

Tags: c#, dll, vbscript, qtp

I am trying to call a C# dll from QTP (uses vbscript).  I have tried a number of things with no success:

- Visual Studio 2010
- Create C# class libary (st.dll)

code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;   

namespace st
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static int GetValue()
        {
            return 34;
        }
    }
}
```

- `regasm /codebase st.dll`

  - fails 'because it is not a valid .NET assembly'

In QTP/vbscript, I have tried

- `extern.Declare micInteger, "GetValue", "e:\st.dll", "GetValue"`

  - Returns message: 'Invalid procedure call or argument'

Regardless of QTP, I would greatly appreciate any insight on how to call the c# dll from a .vbs file.

Comment: Have you marked it as COM-visible? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182157(VS.80).aspx

Comment: I have gone into Properties > Assembly Information and checked 'Make assembly COM-Visible.  Still get the above errors.

Comment: Still struggling ... I removed the 'static' keyword, ran VS 2010 as admin and turned on Properties > Build > Register for COM Interop.

Comment: For those, like, me, who didn't knwo what Qtp was...it's TLA for "Quick Test Professional" and this page here...http://www.advancedqtp.com/ seems to talk a bit about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to get this working by doing the following:

Create a new C# dll in VS 2010.

```
namespace st4
{
    public class st4_functions
    {
        public int GetValue()
        {
            return 34;
        }
    }
}
```

In QTP I added the following lines:

```
Set obj = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("st4.st4_functions", "c:\\st4.dll")
MsgBox obj.GetValue()
```

Thanks to all that responded to my problem.  Though I did not do the COM solution, it got me thinking that I could stay with .NET and led to this solution.  Good job all!

**EDIT:**

I created a blog post to detail the steps and provide additional information:

http://www.solutionmaniacs.com/blog/2012/5/29/qtp-calling-c-dll-in-vbscript.html

Comment: That's certainly better than going via COM. :-)

Comment: I guess `DotNetFactory.CreateInstance()` is unique to QTP?

Answer (score 1):

As Marc said, but I think it merits an answer. If you ensure that your dll will be available though the COM mechanics, your script should be able to call into it with things like *CreateObject*.

[How to register .NET assembly for COM interop](http://blogs.msdn.com/jigarme/archive/2008/04/28/how-to-register-net-assembly-for-com-interop.aspx)

Comment: I made the assembly COM-Visible.  In QTP/vbs I have added:
Dim example
Set example = CreateObject("st.Class1")
But I get an error: ActiveX component can't create object: 'st.Class1'

Answer (score 1):

Your function is static. Static class members can't be matched up to interface members, and if it can't implement a .NET interface then it certainly won't implement a COM interface.

Comment: I have removed the static keyword.  Same problem.  Are there any tutorials on getting a simple class to work in this way without QTP?  I am looking for the simplest example possible to then understand what I need to do.