# VBScript to C# Communication - Passing Objects/Classes

Tags: c#, vbscript, interop

***Background:***

I have a software application which requires scripting in VBScript. I don't have much experience with VBScripting (enough to get me by). However, things like making an object/class, generating a graph structure, and generating other advanced data structures (trees, hash tables, dynamic arrays, etc), are a little bit complicated in VBScript. I don't even know where to begin in terms of generating nodes (I believe everything in VBScript is a pointer, but not entirely sure).

***Question:***
Is it possible to pass entire objects to a C# executable from a VBScript. Then do some algorithms to that object, and pass it back to the VBscript? Or,pass an array of objects (for example, a schematic) to C# executable, build a graph, and send the graph data structure back?

I know it might be easier just to learn how to make these data structures in VBScript, but I am a little curious on the communication capabilities of VBScript and C#.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: There are many methods of interprocess communication, however it really doesn't even need to be an executable. If you make the C# DLL COM visible, you should be able to call methods directly.

Comment: @RonBeyer Hmm interesting...I will look into how to make C# dll visible to VBScripts. Do you have any ideas? (I don't want to start an entire conversation, but if you have something quick that would be great).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769332/how-to-call-c-sharp-dll-function-from-vbscript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451956/calling-c-sharp-dll-in-vbscript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839704/using-dlls-in-vbscript or just search Google for "Call C# dll from vbscript", those were the top 3

Comment: @RonBeyer Thanks! Will do!